# What percentage of saline does water need to be to become hazardous to skin?

Tags: chemistry

I've not gotten many results for this and I've looked up all about chemical lakes like Lake Natron but they seem to be filled with other hazardous substances besides plain sodium chloride. I'm just wondering, how salty would water need to be dangerous, or at least cause irritation quickly

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Seems like you can quickly experiment with this with access to table salt and a glass of water.

Comment: The [Dead sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea) is at a concentration of 342 g/kg of sodium chloride/water, people swim/float there all the time. The maximum possible concentration is 360g/kg at 25 Celsius. What makes you think it could become dangerous?

Comment: Remember, it's always worth including worldbuilding context - why you need to know this. This is to help with getting better and more helpful answers and to avoid closure as "Not about worldbuilding".

Comment: Water **is** hazardous to human skin at any concentration of salt or sugar or whatever. Even zero concentration. Simply put, human skin is not made to be immersed in water for more than a few hours. Prolonged immersion in water **will** destroy human skin. Bad stuff begins to happen after 12 hours of immersion in water, such as the skin losing its ability to keep the external and internal fluids separate, and after 72 hours the skin loses almost all structural integrity. Use your favorite search engine to learn about effects of prolonged immersion.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. That might just be the correct answer. If the Dead sea is already almost saturated and doesn't cause irritation after one minute of exposure,  then it is impossible for any solution to "cause irritation quickly".

Comment: @sphennings simply mixing salt and water doesn't immediately make it saline. Context; there is a settlement in my setting where they extract table salt from a dangerously corrosive lake, and I'm not sure this is plainly feasible with a lake filled with Natron.

Comment: @Quinn **Containing salt is literally the definition of saline**. If you're asking about a corrosive lake, there's probably something more in the lake than just normal salt.  You should [edit] your post so that it's clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

- more like a comment, as I can't leave one

There was a video on youtube, in Afrika (do not remember more specifically) they have business of extracting salt from bottom of shallow lake, so salinity is at about saturation point, they work for hours, as I guess/understood and doing so they smear themselvs with some fat thing for protection, however the guy has shown some scars from, my guess, when it failed for him.

Soo to your quickly - saturated solution won't have immediate effect, and you can't make things quicker, as it already at its max.

Specific time will depend on the skin, does it have some wounds(even tiny ones) or not, overall quality of skin etc. Some specific time is hard to say. Is it repeatedly submerged there or it just one time thing etc.

All in all, that you didn't found some hard numbers is not surpising - as if one just dips a hand in such solution for short time - and the wahes it off - I do not expect anything happen. But if it let's say once a day for short time over longer time(like a year, at work) it may become problematic.

A hour onetime dip, would not recomend, but it a question. Dead sea has about 250g of salt per liter of water, and saturation point is about 357g per liter - significant difference but I would not call it drastic difference. People do swim in dead sea for fun, but for how long and are there any other measures they take in the case I do not know.

I guess looking up for details and reviews/expirience of swiming in dead sea is your starting point, to find out more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

As told by @Jiminy Cricket, Dead Sea has a salinity of 342 g/kg while the maximum solubility of NaCl in water at 25°C is 360 g/kg. Dead Sea is so salty that salt precipitates out of the water and piles up at the bottom of the lake. White crystallized salt covers everything along the shores of the lake.

A visitor to Dead sea says:

> Don’t stay in for too long.
>
> Your body will tell you when to leave the water, you’ll start feeling
> a mild burning sensation, which means it’s time to walk back to the
> hotel and enjoy a nice shower.

This means that

- You can stay in water with maximum salinity (360 g/kg at 25°C) until
  you start feeling a mild burning sensation
- If you have cuts or rashes, then it is painful.
- It is very irritating for the eyes.

Otherwise it is not hazardous.